# How many ways are there to merge two decks of cards such that each deck maintains its order?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Suppose that the first decks is blue, has m cards and has a distinct integer on each card. The second deck is red, has n cards and also has distinct integers on each cars. For simplicity, you can assume each deck is sorted.

Example:
Deck 1 has cards 1,3,5
Deck 2 has cards 2,4

2,1,4,3,5 is allowable
So is 1,2,3,4,5
But 1,4,3,5,2 is not allowable because 2 is supposed to come before 4.

Call this function f(n,m). I can find a recursive formula but I would really like a closed form solution. The recursive formula is
f(n,m)=f(0,m-1) +f(1,m-1)+...+f(n-1,m-1)+f(n,m-1)
With a base case of f(x,1)=x+1

Comment: Please add some context. What have you tried? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I suggest describing this as ways to *merge* two decks, rather than to shuffle them.  Shuffling strongly suggests a rearrangement in order, which you want to avoid.

Answer (score 6):

A configuration is fixed by choosing $n$ out of $n+m$ slots for the red cards, so there are $\binom{n+m}n$ configurations.